# Using :before and :after tags with tables

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to use CSS `:before` and `:after` tags with HTML tables to generate sort of automatic headers and footers, for styling.  They're simply cosmetic, but I'd like to be able to define these things as part of, well, the general table style.

Right now I'm testing with simple rounded borders (using images) trying to place particular images at the right and left side of the element, but I'd like to use this same technique for a number of other styles.

I'm doing something like this:

```
.minTable {
    background-color: #3377AA;
}


.minTable:before {
    background: transparent url("topright.png") scroll no-repeat top right;
    height: 13px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    content: url("topleft.png");
}

.minTable:after {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.1;
  font-size: 1px;
  content:  url("bottomleft.png");
  margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
  height: 13px;
  background: transparent url("bottomright.png") scroll no-repeat bottom right ;
  padding: 0;
}

...

<table class="minTable" width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some other text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This displays roughly how I want, except the width of the element seems to match with the size of the first cell (column), not the width of the table.  So my "right-side" image displays at the right-side of the first table column.

This may be an incredibly stupid way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I'm confused why the :before and :after seem to line up only with the first column, not the entire table.

Can anyone help me understand what the `:before` and `:after` are doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because a table cannot semantically contain a block-level element inside it. Using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements adds that content before and after the content **inside** that parent.To put this into a more easy-to-understand aspect, here's what your final result will *technically* look like in the end:

```
<table class="minTable" width="800" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <div class="before">
    <img src="topleft.png" />
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some other text</td>
  </tr>
  <div class="after">
    <img src="topleft.png" />
  </div>
</table>
```

Of course, the `.before` and `.after` would inherit their respect pseudo-element-related styles too. However, you can imagine that a block-level element inside of a table like that would not act properly because block-level elements don't *belong* inside a table.

Generally, I'd avoid even *trying* to use `:before` and `:after` with tables - that's just asking for a mess.

---

If you're just trying to add corners, I would use CSS to select each corner cell. Something like these:

```css
.minTable > :first-child > tr:first-child > td:first-child /* Top-left corner */
.minTable > :first-child > tr:first-child > td:last-child /* Top-right corner */
.minTable > :last-child > tr:last-child > td:first-child /* Bottom-left corner */
.minTable > :last-child > tr:last-child > td:last-child /* Bottom-right corner */
```

These selectors will not work if: a) you have your table body elements out of order (such as thead, then tfoot, then tbody - it will select elements in tbody for the corners even though tfoot will appear below); b) you have a colgroup element at the beginning of your table; or c) you use rowspans which would cause the bottom cells to actually be a part of the cells in the row above.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.  I was thinking there was more magic involved than there is, but that's very clear.


Thanks for the tip on another method.  I need to do other things besides add corners, but the corners really are my main challenge.

Comment: This explanation is not fully accurate. Actually, block-level _boxes_ prepended/appended to the table do belong to it. But  because of the table-specific CSS formatting rules, these boxes get wrapped by at least 2 levels of anonymous boxes — anonymous `table-cell` box wrapped in the anomymous `table-row` box (as explained in the comment to the answer below).

Answer (score 3):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements display inside the element they are modifying. That means that if you apply them to a table, the browser will try to render it your `display: block` stuff inside the table where it doesn't belong. I suspect the improper width is just an artifact of the particular browser you're using trying to do something it's not supposed to have to do at all. [Edit: Alohci provided the explanation that the browser is silently wrapping the `:after` content in a `table-cell` wrapped by a `table-row`. This would result in the content appearing to be the width of a single column.]

Perhaps your code would work as expected if you apply it to a `<div>` wrapping the `<table>`? Adding a `<div>` in that manner is usually a good idea just to get enough control over the layout of the table.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that makes sense.  I was assuming there'd have to be some smarts in terms of how these would be interpreted for each element they apply to (so there'd be clear rules on how :before would apply to <table>), but in this case it's undefined?

Wrapping the table in a <div> was going to be my workaround, but I was hoping to avoid it.  The goal here was to try to define as much of the table style in a CSS class as possible.  Was trying to abstract as much as possible.

Comment: I'd leave it up to somebody with better understanding of the CSS specification to say whether `table:before` is undefined. Anyway, having no non-semantic markup is a dream not yet realized even with the latest cool standards.

Comment: I started to ask you if my example would be similar to what you'd get if I inserted tags and other content between <table> and <tr>, but it sounds like that's exactly what I was doing =)

Comment: @IanSchorr - I don't think table:before with display:block is undefined, though how well it is implemented is another matter. What should happen, is that the pseudo-elements will be wrapped in [anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), so each pseudo-element will end up in table-row containing a single table-cell, each of which would obviously be displayed in the first table column. This is consistent with the behaviour you describe in your question.